# (Mahara) manually set cookies disappear on the next page

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies, mahara

I'm about to write some code for mahara. I'm trying to store a variable in a cookie. If I do, it will disappear on the next page.

Example:

**foo.php:**

```
...
$myfoo = 'bar';
setcookie('mycookie', $myfoo)
var_dump($_COOKIE) 
...
```

executing foo.php: all the mahara cookies & 'mycookie' is set. Like expected, everything's fine.

**bar.php**

```
...
var_dump($_COOKIE) 
...
```

executing bar.php after foo.php: only mahara standard cookies set, but no 'mycookie'.

I can't really explain that.

Also $_SESSION does not work like intended.

My server is set up correctly, cookies generally work.

Has anyone an idea?

Edit: I see the cookies via var_dump in my foo.php. Even if I stop to set them. They are there. But not on other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$myfoo = 'bar';
setcookie('mycookie', $myfoo, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
var_dump($_COOKIE);
?>
```

Your cookies are expiring because
Specifies when the cookie expires because if expiry time is omitted or set to 0, the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes). Change it to some value like time()+86400*30

For more details: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_network_setcookie.asp

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately, it wasn't. But what is particularly strange:

Yesterday I set other cookies in my "foo.php" with different names. These are still displayed in my foo.php today when I var_dump. But not on another page of mahara, nowhere. So it's not due to the cookie lifetime.

That's the funny thing: In the foo.php I always see the cookies, even if I don't set them again. But only there.

Comment: Ohhh wait, I think Amanjot Kaur's post did it finally for me... I don't know why it didn't work in the first place, but just tried again and yes, it works! Thx!